# Python : How to pass file object as function parameter on python script?

Tags: python

I edited python script like below.

```
def func(file_obj)
    str="test"
    file_obj.write(str)

def main():
    f=open("test.txt", 'w')
    func(f)
    f.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

And then error happened like below.

```
File "test.py", line 2
def func(file_obj)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to pass file object as function parameter?

Answer (score 13):

you forgot to add `:` after the definition. the code looks fine

`def func(file_obj):`